# Get a css box to stop sticking to corner of page when too small

Tags: html, css

## Main problem

I managed to make a box that I wanted to put text in using [W3 schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) but the current problem im having is when I move the pages size around at smaller sizes the right side of the box sticks to the end of the screen, which causes problems if viewing from mobile for example. Something I noticed too was that the left side had less space than the right one.
You can see the problem if you make your window small enough or
[open the site on mobile](https://aechcreations.github.io)

So far i've tried changing the margins on the sides of the text box around with percentages or different pixel sizes but the box is still sticking to the right side no matter what I changed.

Snippet of code that im having problem with:

```
<div class="bodybox">
<p>    according to all known laws of aviation there is no way that a bee should be able to fly. Its wings are too small to get its fat little body off the ground. the bee of course, flies anyways, because bees dont care what humans think is possible.
<br> Yellow black, yellow black, ooh black and yellow! Let's shake it up a little.
<br>Barry! Breakfast is ready!
<br>Coming! 

</p>

</div>
```

```
.bodybox {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #d19dfc;
    width: 95%;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
          
  }
```

Ignore the cringey bee movie script as the text it was the first thing that came to mind for testing the boundaries of the box...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1440px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.bodybox {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #d19dfc;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 7px;
  max-width: 95%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-inline: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bodybox">
  <p> according to all known laws of aviation there is no way that a bee should be able to fly. Its wings are too small to get its fat little body off the ground. the bee of course, flies anyways, because bees dont care what humans think is possible.
    <br> Yellow black, yellow black, ooh black and yellow! Let's shake it up a little.
    <br>Barry! Breakfast is ready!
    <br>Coming!

  </p>

</div>
```